# This submission failed with error code(s) 2003,1201

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-store

We have created a Windows Store app and are running into error code(s) 2003 and 1201 while trying to submit the app to the store. Apparently these errors are not documented in the documentation and there is pretty much absolutely nothing that we can find about these online. Hoping somebody have a knowledge about their resolution and is willing to share it here.
[image]

Answer (score 4):

I recommend you to contact the [Dev Center support](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/support), as they will know what is the cause of this error and will assist you with fixing it. I suspect the problem is some kind of backend issue on their side. You can choose either to create a e-mail based incident on chat with the support live.

You can also post the problem on the dedicated forums (same link as above), to see whether someone else has seen it as well.

Comment: I have reached out to the support team and they say the engineering is looking into it. I shall post any resolution they advise of. So far it is just wait and see :(

Comment: Were you able to fix the problem? I'm getting the same error.

Comment: I had code 1201, and I did nothing but resubmitting the update.  It went through without any problem.  At least code 1201 is an backend error.

Comment: Its September 2020, I am still getting this error :(

Comment: Honestly this is naive. Dev Center has never helped anybody. Actually I haven't received even useful response from them as they try to avoid to say anything that is precise in order to cover the problems. That is how the problems are handled at least in last year or two.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like [error 1201 is a long-standing issue (bug) with the store](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/45468d4f-8b02-4d64-8da6-7a356ab11f18/this-submission-failed-with-error-codes-1201?forum=windowsstore).

From the link above, it looks like some people have been able to overcome this issue by upgrading (or just changing) UWP .NET CORE to a different version, or changing or updating their version of Visual Studio.

It looks like you have also posted on this link, and are using UWP Platform 6.2.0.  I believe this version is currently considered to be a "Preview" version.

If I was you, I would try rolling back to a previous version (via [NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/package-manager-console)).  I would suggest you try 6.1.4 (latest stable. as of 5/20/2018), or even earlier 6.0.8

Comment: We changed the UWP platform to 6.1.4 and now the error 2003 is gone but 1201 is still with us.

Comment: Can you try changing to 6.0.8?

Comment: Did but 1201 stayed with us 

Comment: Have you tried with Visual Studio 2015 (instead of 2017)?

Comment: If we do that then we may lose the functionality that was introduced to our app so right now going back to 2015 does not look a good option for us :(

Answer (score 0):

In case it is helpful to others, I am sharing my solution that worked on 2021-11-12.
I encountered error 1201:

[image]

I deleted the submission and resubmitted **exactly the same** package and it worked. It appeared to be a Microsoft Store glitch.

Comment: Does not help for me, same error: This submission failed with error code(s) 1201. More info about the error(s) can be found here.