# UWP app update submission failed with error code 1201

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-store

I have a UWP Xamarin Forms app that is in the Microsoft Store.  I've updated this app in the partner center several times without trouble.  My last update was 1/31/2020.

Yesterday I submitted another update but it failed with the following message:

> This submission failed with error code(s) 1201

In searching I've come across threads like this [This submission failed with error code(s) 2003,1201](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50424149/this-submission-failed-with-error-codes-2003-1201) which point to problems with Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform, but I've not changed that in this submission. Here's a listing of the nuget packages that I changed with this new submission:

- Microsoft AppCenter 2.1.1 to 2.6.4
- Xamarin.Forms 4.2.0.848062 to 4.4.0.991640
- I've also added Xamarin.Essentials 1.3.1

How can I go about troubleshooting this to figure out what the problem is?

Update:

I've determined it is not AppCenter nor Xamarin.Essentials.

Updating from Xamarin.Forms 4.2.0.848062 to 4.3.x OR 4.4.x causes the problem.

In addition, I noticed something I didn't see before:  There is a 'silent' error when packaging for the store with Xamarin.Forms 4.3/4.4.  This error is NOT present with Xamarin.Forms 4.2.x.  The error is:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\Microsoft.AppXPackage.Targets(3385,5): error MSB6006: "mspdbcmf.exe" exited with code 1106.

<s>It seems likely that the above error is related to the submission error.</s>

Update 2:

I found the following post on the mspdbcmf error:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/855376/mspdbcmfexe-exited-with-code-1106.html

I used the workaround described and I was able to get rid of the silent build error but my app submission still fails with error 1201.

Comment: Well, you could try to narrow down the scope of the issue. First roll back the version of `AppCenter` if the submission still got error, then you could roll back other libraries. And I found the same case in MSDN, our team member will follow up, please pay attention to the following update.

Comment: I've updated my question with additional information.  Xamarin.Forms is the culprit.

Comment: Our team has replied your case, please check [it](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/d9e57d2b-a589-4b5f-a525-6e5670a42c1e/microsoft-store-submission-error-1201-when-trying-to-submit-update-to-app?forum=wpsubmit&prof=required).